# Default mode of operation in TLS cipher suites

Tags: tls, modes-of-operation, openssl, ciphersuite

I've been trying to evaluate the security of a list of cipher suites and I've come across cipher suites, not explicitly featuring a mode of operation.

Form this list ([openvpn --show-tls](https://pastebin.com/raw/V4898xRr)), one of such cipher suites would be:

```
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
```

As the cipher suites are provided by the underlying SSL library (OpenSSL 1.0.2g), I assume there must be a default mode, if not explicitly defined.

What mode would be used in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [official list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4), you'll see that the official cipher suite name always has the mode explicitly stated; each AES-based transform is explicitly called out to be CBC, GCM or CCM.

Going through the OpenSSL source code, we find that the ciphersuite you cited has the value `0x00, 0x37`, that is, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.  Hence, CBC is the mode being implicit.  I suspect this is implicit because OpenSSL predates TLS 1.2; in TLS 1.1 and prior, CBC was the only block cipher mode allowed (and hence there was no need to call it out); once the started supporting TLS 1.2, they didn't feel like they should go back and modify the name strings they used for existing ciphersuites.

Comment: A more convenient reference than the source code is about 2/3 of the way down the man page for `ciphers(1)` on your system [or on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer, as well as the complimentary link @dave_thompson_085

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Nice. Didn't know that. But I prefer testssl's mapping: https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mapping.html